# Curious as to know why this doesn't work MySQL

Tags: mysql

What I'm trying to do is get every teacher name involved with the class_id provided. And it does nothing, very strange.The tables the query is connected to:

```
+----+------------+----------+
| id | teacher_id | class_id |
+----+------------+----------+
|  1 |          1 |        2 |
|  6 |          1 |        4 |
| 10 |          2 |        3 |
|  5 |          2 |        5 |
|  4 |          3 |        1 |
|  7 |          3 |        3 |
|  9 |          4 |        2 |
|  2 |          4 |        4 |
|  3 |          5 |        1 |
|  8 |          5 |        5 |
+----+------------+----------+
10 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> select * from classes;
+----------+------------+------------------------+
| id_class | class_name | responsible_teacher_id |
+----------+------------+------------------------+
|        1 | Geography  |                      2 |
|        2 | Reading    |                      1 |
|        3 | Science    |                      3 |
|        4 | History    |                      5 |
|        5 | Arithmetic |                      4 |
+----------+------------+------------------------+
5 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> select * from teachers;
+----+------------+-------------+-----------+------------+------------+-------------+----------------------------------+
| id | first_name | middle_name | last_name | birthdate  | subject_id | current_age | md5                              |
+----+------------+-------------+-----------+------------+------------+-------------+----------------------------------+
|  1 | Oliver     | Weed        | Saxon     | 1983-01-03 |          2 |          38 | 4bf51ce48af83dba7c8390a7222db991 |
|  2 | Dexter     | Tristan     | Morgan    | 1980-12-11 |          5 |          40 | be96d6213828fd09538d8b1357907d54 |
|  3 | Deborah    | Ocean       | Morgan    | 1985-06-10 |          2 |          35 | ba6869ece0a74ca9987b83b4f840405b |
|  4 | George     | Kai         | Smith     | 1965-01-03 |          6 |          56 | ccec54863dbb6b63e55d495341fd9a63 |
|  5 | Chi        | Kai         | Chian     | 1979-10-03 |          3 |          41 | 2291ce528bf05eff905af1eecd9bc53b |
+----+------------+-------------+-----------+------------+------------+-------------+----------------------------------+
5 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

And the query:

```
select first_name
     , middle_name
     , last_name 
  FROM teachers_seth t 
  JOIN classes_sethputz c 
    ON c.responsible_teacher_id = t.id 
  JOIN teachers_classes_sethputz t_c 
    ON t_c.class_id = c.id_class 
   AND t_c.teacher_id = t.id 
 WHERE c.id_class = 1;
```

And what the query returned each time I ran it with a different class_id:

```
c.id_class = 1;
Empty set (0,00 sec)


c.id_class = 2;
+------------+-------------+-----------+
| first_name | middle_name | last_name |
+------------+-------------+-----------+
| Oliver     | Weed        | Saxon     |
+------------+-------------+-----------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)


c.id_class = 3;
+------------+-------------+-----------+
| first_name | middle_name | last_name |
+------------+-------------+-----------+
| Deborah    | Ocean       | Morgan    |
+------------+-------------+-----------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)


c.id_class = 4;
Empty set (0,00 sec)

c.id_class = '5';
Empty set (0,00 sec)
```

Thanks. This is really strange for me.

Comment: Sorry but there is no column with teachers name and I can also see no table teachers_classes_sethputz. Please include all used tables. Best make a working example on sqlfiddle

Comment: @Claus Bonnhoff, teachers_classes_sethputz is teachers_classes. Ha! I tried to remove my name from all queries so I could stay anonymous. That is all the tables, teachers has no <name> column, instead it has first, middle, and last _name columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have too much joining going on for your question, you have 3 tables, teachers, classes and a matrix that links them many-many.

You are joining the classes table directly to the teachers table with the responsible_teacher_id column, this should not be there if you want the teachers involved with the classes. What you are doing is saying if the teachers are the responsible teacher AND the teacher is involved in the class and that is rarely the case so you get very few hits.

So to solve it, start with the class table (classes_sethputz), as that is what you appear to be doing and then add in the matrix table (teachers_classes_sethputz) by joining it then add in the teachers table (teachers_seth) by joining it to the matrix table (teachers_classes_sethputz).

```
SELECT first_name
     , middle_name
     , last_name 
FROM classes_sethputz c
  JOIN teachers_classes_sethputz t_c
    ON t_c.class_id = c.id_class 
  JOIN teachers_seth t 
    ON t.id = t_c.teacher_id
 WHERE c.id_class = 5;
```

Comment: Very good, thanks for that. After putting a more couple hours into it I ended up making it work, but I didn't know why it worked compared to my old code. Ha! Thanks for explaining it. @Mark B